Traveling on tourist visa to India, problematic if itinerary deviates from what was on application?
I recently received an approved tourist visa (1 year validity) to India. At the time I submitted it I had a set list of cities I wished to visit. However, our party has decided we may wish to visit an additional city. By and large, the list of sites I'm visiting will be the same as what I submitted in my application, other than this addition.
Will this be problematic in any way? If so, I'll stick to what was submitted, but it would be nice to know we have a little flexibility with travel.

I think you are fine here. We got a 1 year e-visa in January and it didn't say anything about a specific itinerary and it specifically lists 31 airports where you are allowed to enter. This is  multi entry Visa so tying it to a single itinerary makes no sense.
